# Theorem 1.2.7 in Sturmfel's Algorithms in Invariant Theory: Hilbert Series and Monomial Ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra, groebner-basis, monomial-ideals

This is a question on a proof of Theorem 1.2.7 in Sturmfel's Algorithms in Invariant Theory. I will restate the whole proof up to where I am confused.

First some notation.
Let $\sigma_i(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ be the $i$-th elementary symmetric polynomial.
Let $h_i(x_1, \ldots,x_n)$ be the $i$-th complete symmetric polynomial.
Let $I$ be the ideal of $\mathbb{C}[\overline{x}, \overline{y}] = \mathbb{C}[x_1, \ldots, x_n, y_1, \ldots, y_n]$ generated by $\sigma_i(x_1, \ldots, x_n) - y_i$.

Next I will state the following useful theorem without proof:

$\textbf{Theorem 1.2.6:}$ Let $I$ be any ideal of $\mathbb{C}[\overline{x}]$ and fix any monomial order.
Then the residue classes of standard monomials (monomials that are not in the initial ideal of $I$, $\text{init}(I)$) form a $\mathbb{C}$ vector space basis of $\mathbb{C}[\overline{c}] / I$.

$\textbf{Theorem 1.2.7:}$ The unique reduced Groebner basis of $I$ with respect to the lexicographic monoimial order induced by $x_1 > x_2 > \cdots > x_n > y_1 > y_2 > \cdots > y_n$ is
$$G = \left\{ h_k(x_k, \ldots, x_n) + \sum_{i = 1}^l (-1)^i h_{k - i}(x_k, \ldots, x_n) \cdot y_i \mid k = 1, \ldots, n \right\}.$$

$\textbf{Proof}$: First, note that for all $k = 1, \ldots, n$ that
$$h_k(x_k, \ldots, x_n) + \sum_{i = 1}^l (-1)^i h_{k - i}(x_k, \ldots, x_n) \cdot \sigma_i(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = 0.$$
This, $G \subseteq I$.

Now grade $\mathbb{C}[\overline{x}, \overline{y}]$ by $\deg(x_i) = 1$ and $\deg(y_i) = i)$.
Thus, $I$ is homogenous and $R = \mathbb{C}[\overline{x}, \overline{y}] / I$ is isomorphic as a graded algebra to $\mathbb{C}[\overline{x}]$.
Thus, the Hilbert Series of $R$ is $\frac{1}{(1 - z)^{-n}}$.
By $\textbf{Theorem 1.2.6}$ we have that the Hilbert series of $\mathbb{C}[\overline{x}, \overline{y}] / \text{init}(I)$ is also $\frac{1}{(1 - z)^{-n}}$.

Now consider the ideal $J = \langle x_1, x_2^2, \ldots, x_n^n\rangle$.
This is the initial ideal of $G$.
Clearly $J \subseteq \text{init}(I)$.
(*And now this is where I start getting confused*)
Our assertion states that these two ideals are equal.
For the proof, it is sufficient to verify that the Hilbert series of $R' = \mathbb{C}[\overline{x}, \overline{y}] / J$ is equal to the Hilbert series of $R$.

So here are my questions

1: When the proof says "Our assertion states that these two ideals are equal" what assertion are they referring to?

2: More importantly, why is it sufficient to verify that these Hilbert series are equivalent?

Comment: You absolutely cannot claim this, for instance $I=(x)$ and $J=(y)$ in $\Bbb C[x,y]$. You need to provide more context about the problem you're trying to solve in an edit to this post. Please **type** the claim that's giving you trouble instead of linking the book or using a picture.